# Symbol resolving for C++ classes

Tags: c++, qt, dll, symbols

How to resolve a symbol in dynamic library? It doesn't matter, with `QLibrary` or with `::GetProcAddress`

For example: `QSharedPointer< IPlugin > getInstance(void)`

I tried next combinations:

- `QSharedPointer< IPlugin > getInstance(void)`
- `class QSharedPointer< class IPlugin > getInstance(void)`

Bur resolving always fails.

Depends shows next symbols: `class QSharedPointer<class IPlugin> PluginInstance(void)` or undecorated `?PluginInstance@@YA?AV?$QSharedPointer@VIPlugin@@@@XZ`

Comment: Is `getInstance()` a global function?

Comment: Yes. Signature inside .dll code is `__declspec(dllexport) QDharedPointer< IPlugin > getInstance()`

Comment: Have you declared the signature inside your code somewhere, or included a header file containing the signature?

Comment: @RobbieE I don't understand you well. Signature is declared in header file of .dll, implementation of function is in .cpp. It doesn't matter, where to declare it

Comment: Yes, but the code using the symbol exported from your .dll needs to know the signature as well, and must be declared `__declspec(dllimport)`

Comment: @RobbieE My application don't has a signature in compile time. Only .dll has. Your comment is related to cases with compile time linking of .dll-s (or with delay loading).